# How to run schema creation sql script in mssql with nodejs?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure-functions, sqlcmd

I have my code deployed in Azure Function App and using NodeJS I am trying to execute a sql script on SQL Server database. To work this out I have used NPM package [sqlcmd-runner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlcmd-runner).

Here is the code I am using:

```
module.exports.dumpScriptinDatabase = (dbConfig, context) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sqlcmd({
        server: dbConfig.server,
        database: dbConfig.options.database,
        username: dbConfig.userName,
        password: dbConfig.password,
        encryptedConnection: true,
        inputFiles: [`${__dirname}\\db.sql`]
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        reject('Error dumping script!!')
    })
    .done(() => {
        resolve('Dumping script completed.')
    });
});
```

I am getting all the database details in `dbConfig` variable. Also `db.sql` creates the tables, views etc. in the schema.

The issue I am facing is this module never returns me error in case of failure and it also does not executes successfully. The server returns 502 error code on execution.

One thing I am able to debug is that the npm package code uses sqlcmd to execute the script.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: db-migrate package using npx command or install it globally, you could run sql file .

Answer (score 1):

So I've tested this using several source files, it's working ok, scripts are run successfully.

**index.js**

```
const dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.json');
const dumpScript = require('./dumpScript.js');

console.log('Running script');
dumpScript.dumpScriptinDatabase(dbConfig, 'context').then(() => {
   console.log('Script complete');
}).catch ( (err) => {
   console.error('Script error: ', err); 
});
```

**dumpScript.js**

```
const sqlcmd = require('sqlcmd-runner');

module.exports.dumpScriptinDatabase = (dbConfig, context) => {
    return sqlcmd({
        server: dbConfig.server,
        database: dbConfig.options.database,
        username: dbConfig.userName,
        password: dbConfig.password,
        encryptedConnection: true,
        inputFiles: [`${__dirname}\\db.sql`]
    });
}
```

**dbConfig.json**

```
{
   "server": "sql_server",
   "options": {
       "database": "test_db"
   },
   "userName": "user",
   "password": "password"

}
```

I've simplified the dumpScript.js file, we can simply return the promise from the sqlcmd function rather than using .then and .catch.

We then handle this in index.js.

A couple of things I'd mention, you need the sqlcmd utility of a fairly recent version on *PATH* for this to work.

Also, you might need to modify the index.js script, I'm loading dbConfig from a .json file, you're probably doing something different.

Comment: Did you tried it after deploying to cloud?
Because for me it worked when I tried running function app locally!

Comment: I didn't try it on the cloud! Though the only difference should be dbconfig.

Comment: When I debugged in cloud, it seems sql-cmdrunner package tries to create a separate process.

[var sqlcmd = process.spawn(command.path, command.args);](https://github.com/mikeobrien/node-sqlcmd-runner/blob/master/src/process.js)

This works when you run locally but not once deployed to cloud.

Comment: Yeah, this may be an issue that prevents using this module on the cloud. If sqlcmd is not present I don't think it will ever work! You might have to use another module.

Comment: Locally it will works, but on server the machine is to be prepared to run sqlcmd. I am struggling with ubuntu, yet after installing sqlcmd that passed test, yet sqlcmd-runner is not working.